Firebase Realtime Database Rules for collaboration between users on certain data
I am using Firebase Realtime Database.
I am working on a new feature to allow one authenticated user to give access to another authenticated user so both can work on it.
The structure of the data is
{
  "dataTables": {
    "myUserId": {
      "2-15-2023": {
        "myTableId": {
          "description": "This table was auto generated to show you a demo of the application. You can leave it, edit it or delete it.",
          "name": "Demo 1 Past",
          "rows": {
            "-NLBD8RiJeyZpnKg8iKI": {
              "lastEdit": 1676495720665,
              "name": "This is a marked text.",
              "priority": 1
            },
            "-NLBD8RjFcXNKJEWFefR": {
              "lastEdit": 1676495720665,
              "name": "This is a regular task. Tasks can be edited by pressing the gear icon at the right side of a task.",
              "priority": 2,
              "status": 1
            }
        }
    }
}

The structure of the data that controls the access that a user has to other tables
{
  "sharedTables" {
    "myUserId": {
      "myTableId": {
        "data" : "data"
      }
    }
  }
}

The current rules for the database are the following:
"dataTables": {
  "$ownerUid": {
    ".read": "$ownerUid === auth.uid",  
    ".write": "$ownerUid === auth.uid",
    "$tableDate": {  
      "$tableId": {  
        ".read": "$ownerUid === auth.uid || root.child('sharedTables').child($ownerUid).child($tableId).exists()",
        ".write": "$ownerUid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}

With this rule, regular users can still access their data.
But when I try to access /dataTables/myUserId/2-15-2023/myTableId I am not allowed.
Basically trying to access the table that I was given access to.
Can I access inside $ownerUid to $tableId from the nesting?
Am I going in the right direction?

"Can I access inside $ownerUid to $tableId from the nesting?" Yup, that should work fine. Variables are available in nested scopes. ---
"But when I try to access /dataTables/myUserId/2-15-2023/myTableId I am not allowed." Can you show the minimal code that does this and doesn't work? In that code, please make sure to prove that the state of the app is meeting the requirement of your rules in a way that we can all validate (i.e. log the UID, hardcode all paths, etc).

@puf-FrankvanPuffelen can you please check my comment if it is secure?
I managed to write something and in tests if performs well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78829102/3102325

When I try to access $tableId above its declaration I get an error
Error saving rules - Line 23: Unknown variable '$tableId'.
    "$ownerUid": {           ".read": "auth != null && ($ownerUid === auth.uid || root.child('sharedTables').child(auth.uid).child($tableId).exists())",         "$tableDate": {           "$tableId": {             ".read": "auth != null && ($ownerUid === auth.uid || root.child('sharedTables').child(auth.uid).child($tableId).exists())",             ".write": "$ownerUid === auth.uid"           }         }       }

Please don't post additional information as an answer as it makes the system think that your question has been addressed. Instead, add additional information by clicking the edit link under it. Also note, that I asked for the code that accesses the information and doesn't work. More rules and more words are not necessarily the best path forward, as they're ambiguous - where code is not.

@AlexMamo I posted it in a comment because it is the response that I figured out.
It can help others who might look for something similar

This one below works perfectly.
I have access to all my own tables under /dataTables/UID/TABLES.
And I also have access to individual tables that are specified in /sharedTables
 "dataTables": {
  "$ownerUid": {
    ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === $ownerUid",
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $ownerUid",
    "$tableDate": {
      "$tableId": {
        ".read": "auth != null && (auth.uid === $ownerUid || root.child('sharedTables').child(auth.uid).child($tableId).exists())",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $ownerUid"
      }
    }
  }
}


I am able to have access to $tableDate/$tableId but then it does bypass the validation when I try to get all my own tables dataTables/uid/ALL-TABLES
